# Errors when sending a prompt to a specific LLM on Replicate through an API call

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm implementing an application on the web that sends a prompt to a specific LLM on Replicate through an API call. I'm working with the framework angular. I have already created a container for the prompt and a button on the application that is supposed to return the response of the prompt in question. However, when I go to localhost and type a prompt and press the button, nothing happens, and instead, I get this error in the browser console.

"Access to fetch at 'https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status."

" chunk-UWKZTWKI.js?v=0a44332c:63
POST https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions net::ERR_FAILED"

I looked into the problem and apparently, it's due to CORS issues. However, I believe I have followed the documentation on Replicate correctly to make a prediction, and I have also specified the API key, which should also be correct. Would anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you calling a 3rd party API directly from the angular app? I'm not familiar with replicate but for security reasons, you wouldn't want to do that. You will end up leaking the tokens for the API in the js. The alternative would be to create a server-side API on either nodejs or anything else and have that call the API.

Comment: @V.S Yes indeed I set up an Angular service that is designed to interact with a third-party api for language model inference via Replicate